# Сбои Mysql. Отклонение запросов

Tags: mysql

Всем привет!
Возникла проблема с Mysql. 
Для наглядности приведу схему работы(сорри за косорукость при рисовании).
[image]

В общем клиентское ПО,посылает данные серверу, и они ложится в Mysql.
-Данные посылаются пакетами, один раз в сутки.

Теперь о плохом.

"ПО Начальника" - Делает запрос на сервер(напрямую Mysql) и получает данные.

Эта вся система работает около 1,5-2 лет.
База Mysql находящаяся на сервере собственно никогда не чистилась/оптимизировалась.
А теперь сама проблема(ы).
С недавнего времени Mysql  стал отказываться принимать запросы.
Выражается это так 
"Mysql has gone away". + намного чаще стали биться таблицы.
После перезапуска службы и восстановления всех табличек, Mysql живет, до первого приёма данных.Потом снова mysql has gone away.

---

Размер БД: 1,93ГБ

Вопрос:
-
Как выйти из этой ситуации?
-Замена платформы БД невозможна.
-Оптимизация довольно проблематичная,но решаемая процедура.

Вообще из за чего Mysql плывет
-Большой размер БД?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Официалы пишут [следующее](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) по ошибке.

Вполне возможно что изначально запросы к БД кривые. 2 Гига это не так много для того чтобы повесить мускул маленькими запросами.

А вот если запросы берут кучу, просто кучу данных и никак их не фильтруют, то тогда может и упасть БД, разорваться сессия из-за долгого ожидания и прочее. Вариантов много.

Пробуй глянуть в логи что там пишут, попробуй вырубить комп начальника. Возможно что именно он делает глупые,большие, ненужные запросы в БД, выбирает тонны записей и т.д. скорее всего оптимизировать скрипты нужно.

Друпаловцы предлагают сделать [так](http://drupal.org/node/259580)

Быть может случилось именно то что не предусмотрели и MyIsqm не подходит изначально на большое кол-во INSERTов, и нужен InnoDB как вариант. Но тут смотреть нужно.

Comment: Запросы проверил, большие, но ровные=)
Буду пробовать оптимизировать/урезать.
Раньше все норм работало

Comment: Большие но ровные? Это как?

Тут просто нужно понять из-за чего обрыв происходит.

Comment: С обрывом разобрался. 
Смысл в непродуманности ПО Сервера.
В таблице Mysql есть поле с уникальными значениями.Пример Таблица "buy" - Поле "BuyID"
Когда приходит запись которая дублирует существующую,Mysql собственно вываливает ошибку Duplicate entry '9-199146' for key 'SyncKey'.
хз зачем, ПО Сервера пытается восстановить таблицу, а так как БД довольно большая(1,9гб),этот процесс занимает продолжительное время,не дожидаясь отклика,по снова пытается восстановить табличку.
Итого:  Mysql не вывозит и отказывается принимать запросы.